# Spacing when printing values in a python dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, spacing

I want to print values from a dictionary without any spacing.

This is a test of my code:

```
d = {}
d["char12"] = "test"
d["char22"] = "test"
print d["char12"],
print d["char22"]
```

the output is

```
test test
```

but i need it to be:

```
testtest
```

is there a way to remove that automatic spacing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: combine the print statements

```
print d["char12"]+d["char22"]
```

Option 2: use stdout.write

```
import sys
...
sys.stdout.write(d["char12"]) # write without a separator
print d["char22"]
```

Comment: The first one runs against the grain IMO. The second requires an import, and multiple writes.

Comment: using sys.stdout.write worked perfectly, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format) is one of the many options.

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format):

> This method of string formatting is the new standard in Python 3, and
>   should be preferred to the % formatting described in String Formatting
>   Operations in new code.

You use it like this:

```
print '{}{}'.format(d["char12"], d["char22"])
```

This will also work:

```
print('{char12}{char22}'.format(**d))
```

which lets you use the dictionary keys in the format string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `join()`

```
d = {}
d["char12"] = "test"
d["char22"] = "test"

print ''.join((d["char12"], d["char22"]))
```

output: `testtest`

Answer (score 0):

**One way:**

```
import sys
d = {}
d["char12"] = "test"
d["char22"] = "test"
sys.stdout.write(d["char12"])
sys.stdout.write(d["char22"])
```

You can use this!

Or you can use **another way:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
d = {}
d["char12"] = "test"
d["char22"] = "test"
print(d["char12"], end="")
print(d["char22"], end="")
```

Answer (score -1):

To print a dictionary's values without spaces:

```
print(''.join(d.values())
```

Dictionaries are not ordered, so if order is important, you should use an OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()
d["char12"] = "test"
d["char22"] = "test"

print(''.join(d.values())
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `join()`, but it's probably not a good idea to select your data structure on the basis of being able to print out its values without spaces.